# consulta con subquery toma demasiado tiempo

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Como podria eficientar esta consulta, ya que la subconsulta esta haciendo que tarde horrores ya que son muchos registros. El problema que veo es que la subconsulta solo verifica que el registro no exista en la tabla pagoterceros. ¿Alguna idea?

```
SELECT distinct DIR.ID, DIR.NombreC AS EMPRESA FROM TramiteFactura AS tfac
            JOIN Directorio AS DIR on tfac.Empresa = DIR.ID
            JOIN Proveedores AS PRO ON tfac.Proveedor = PRO.ID
            WHERE tfac.Importe>0 AND tfac.Importe IS NOT NULL AND tfac.IdTramiteFactura NOT IN(SELECT PT.Factura FROM pagoterceros AS PT)
            AND PRO.Estatus ='ACTIVO'
            AND tfac.Estatus IN('EN ELABORACIÓN DE FORMA DE PAGO', 'REGISTRADA Y PAGADA', 'SOBREPAGADA', 'PAGADA')
            ORDER BY DIR.NombreC ASC
```

Comment: Hacer un outer join?

Comment: Poner índices en las columnas de texto que intentas comparar. Comparar textos siempre es mucho más lento que comparar enteros, a no ser que tengas un índice en la columna. En ese caso es practicamente lo mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad, siempre utilizando una sub-consulta, es expresarla en SQL de la misma forma que la has expresado en palabras.

Esto puede resultar más óptimo para el motor, que necesita nada más que hacer un lookup al índice para cada fila que es candidata a pertenecer al resultado. Un buen optimizador de SQL debiera encontrar el equivalente por si mismo, pero es probable que mySQL se esté quedando corto.

Me refiero a utilizar la cláusula `not exists`, en lugar de `not in`. Puede que con `not in` el motor esté perdiendo de vista que puede utilizar el índice para determinar la no coincidencia. También puede que, si hay millones de registros en cada tabla, esté realmente ejecutando millones de veces la consulta que trae la tabla completa solo para finalmente hacer la comparación, que si encima se realiza sin un índice, ¡zaz!, horas de ejecución.

Solo podríamos saber lo que está ocurriendo realmente viendo el plan de ejecución de la consulta.

Mi sugerencia es que lo cambies por algo como:

```
       inner join Directorio AS DIR on tfac.Empresa = DIR.ID
       inner join Proveedores AS PRO ON tfac.Proveedor = PRO.ID
 where tfac.Importe > 0 
   and PRO.Estatus ='ACTIVO'
   and tfac.Estatus IN ('EN ELABORACIÓN DE FORMA DE PAGO', 'REGISTRADA Y PAGADA', 'SOBREPAGADA', 'PAGADA')
   and not exists (select 1 from pagoterceros AS PT where PT.Factura = tfac.IdTramiteFactura)
 order by DIR.NombreC ASC
```

Debes asegurarte que haya un índice por el campo `Factura` en la tabla `pagoterceros`.

Ya que el volumen de datos es alto, sugiero también que dediques tiempo a optimizar la consulta SIN esta condición. Evalúa los planes de ejecución, asegúrate de tener los índices necesarios y haber realizado otros ajustes que sean necesarios.

Quita también todo el ruido que puedas de la consulta, ya que esto puede terminar confundiendo al optimizador. Por ejemplo, yo he quitado la condición `tfac.Importe IS NOT NULL`, que es superflua, dado que ya tienes la condición `tfac.Importe > 0` y, creeme, `Importe` será mayor que cero solo si no tiene `NULL`.

Comment: Me ayudo bastante tu guia, al final pude simplificar el tiempo de ejecución a apenas medio segundo.

Comment: Me alegra haber sido de ayuda. ¿Cuánto se estaba tardando antes?

Comment: alrededor de 5 minutos